# Unable to resize partition through Gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I tried to resize it but it the slide bar wont even move. It's not mounted and I cant boot into windows because Lenovo screen pops up then goes black then switches to Ubuntu. I need more memory for my Ubuntu.

[image: My partitions]

Comment: Which partition do you want to resize? if it's root partition then you need to create unallocated space first

Comment: I want to resize /sda3

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to shrink sda3, which has an exclamation mark beside it, then you need to ensure that Windows was properly shut down first.  You can see more details in GParted by selecting the partition and using the **Partition -> Information** menu option.

If Windows doesn't boot, then you might need to boot from Windows Install / Recovery media and run `chkdsk /f /r` on sda3 (or likely C: in Windows).

Comment: The flags /f and /r are kind of mutually exclusive. One's a **fix**, one is a **bad block scan**. The more correct command would be `chkdsk /f c:` :-)

Comment: From what I've read, /r checks for bad blocks and tries to recover data whereas /f just tries to fix errors on the disk.  For details on parameters I looked at [chkdsk](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chkdsk.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: According the the doc you cite, both /f and /r require a lock. It also indicates what I said earlier... one's a fix/repair, the other is the longer bad block scan. You probably wouldn't do them at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

**First, you'll need to get Windows to properly boot up using a Windows install/repair disc.**

**note**: You don't need "*more memory for my Ubuntu*", you need "*more disk space for Ubuntu*".

To make more room for Ubuntu, you'll need to **shrink** your Windows C: drive, partition /dev/sda3. You'll want to boot into Windows and use Windows own `Disk Management` application to do that.

Then you can boot a Ubuntu Live DVD and use `gparted` to do the rest of the work.

## Backup your important data first, as partition manipulation can corrupt or loose data. You've been warned.

**Keep these things in mind:**

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**So do this... short answer...**

After shrinking your Windows partition, boot the Ubuntu Live DVD...

- `swapoff` on sda8
- **move** sda8 partition all the way left
- **resize** the left side of the sda9 partition all the way left
- `swapon` on sda8

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try running the machine from a USB with live session.

First at all be sure that Windows is completely shutted down, not hibernated, and that your data is backed up.
Dowload Ubuntu or Linux Mint iso image. 
First erase you usb, and then burn using `dd` (its a easy way).

```
sudo umount /dev/sdX && sudo mkfs /dev/sdX
sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu_or_lm.iso of=/dev/sdX --status=progress
```

When it finish, you are ready to reboot from usb. 
In the live session, open a terminal and run `gparted` with elevated privileges `sudo gparted` and just resize the partition.

Comment: That's not a complete answer, or an accurate comment. Sorry.

Comment: It's a very short but effective answer. I had the same problem.

Comment: No, it's not complete. For example... how/where do you "sudo gparted" and what do you do once you get there? You might think... well of course, open a terminal and type "sudo gparted"... I might think... why not just start gparted from the Unity dashboard? Then what? See my answer.

Comment: ok, ok, you are right. I was from my phone.